# Ruby TK library not found

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

I am trying to run a simple ruby program on windows platform using 'tk' library but when I run the program I am getting following error:

```
`require': no such file to load -- tk (LoadError)
```

I checked tk docs on http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html

it says I have to install active tcl and have to compile ruby source to generate library but when I am following the steps given in the doc I am getting following error

```
C:\Ruby192\Ruby192>win32\configure.bat --prefix=c:\Ruby192
        cl -nologo -MD rtname.c user32.lib -link > nul
Checking unicows.lib
Creating Makefile.new
find: `=': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cl' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

I have visual c++ installed, set all required paths..

not getting what is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use latest http://rubyinstaller.org it has all Tk and bindings inside